# Switching between users in XFCE / LightDM without locking session

Tags: login, xfce, lightdm, switch-user, multiple-users

When I was using KDE with KDM it was very simple to switch users. After I logged in multiple sessions I could easily switch by pressing `ctrl+alt+f7` and `ctrl+alt+f8` and so on. It was seamless because:

- the tty number was fixed, starting from #7
- if the session was unlocked it wouldn't ask for a password.
- if a session was unlocked then after a timeout xscreensaver would kick in a lock sessions automatically.

Now I've moved to XFCE with LightDM and the process is more frustrating because:

- I keep getting asked for a password every time
- the tty number keeps changing and is confusing. With one session it's tty7 but with another session tty7 gets blacked out and moves to tty8
- it's confusing and inconsistent changing between sessions

How do I configure so that I can switch sessions easily as I did in KDE/KDM?

I suspect this might requiring enabling multiple Xorg processes? So multiple lightdm seats maybe? But not sure how.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide OS & release details.

Answer (score 0):

In Xubuntu 20.04 you have to add an item to the panel - the one with white arrow to the left in orange circle. Dunno how it is named in English, probably something like "Action buttons" or so. Your name will appear at its place. When you click at it, pull-down menu appears with "switch user" as one of the items. You'll have to enter target account's password though...